# cms with spring framework support

Tags: java, spring, content-management-system

We are building web self care for mobile operator. We expected that system will have about 3 000 000 users and 30 000 visits per day. Java based, extensive use of Spring for billing system integration, oracle db.

Project have series of supplementary requirements such as:

- have 3 versions of public site targeted to:

  1. broadband internet with main browsers support
  2. mobile devices
  3. specific touch screen devices
- page layout, text and media content from public part of the site will be depended on user profile (region, language, tariff plan)
- privileged users (admins) should be able to customize css, pages layout (page composition), site menus, some text/media content from admin area
- full text search by site content and by some internal billing system data structures with search widget in public part of the site
- visitors/service usage statistics gathering

It seems for us that this set of requirements could be fulfilled by reuse of some java based CMS.

1) We are trying to evaluate would we get some benefits in case we get some ready open sources java CMS. Or is it simpler to build this parts ourselves?

2) We get the list of more or less related to our technology stack CMSs (mainly we are trying to find solution that allow us embed widgets with logic driven by our Spring services and ability to plugin our user storage and authentication processing):

- http://www.magnolia-cms.com
- http://www.onehippo.com/
- http://www.riotfamily.org/index.html
- http://demo.jease.org/documentation/
- http://www.opencms.org/en/
- http://www.jahia.org/cms
- http://daisycms.org
- http://www.day.com/day/en.html
- http://www.alfresco.com/
- http://www.nuxeo.com

We will be appreciated for any recommendations about one of this products or any thoughts which one will suite our needs better.

Comment: Also try [Liferay Portal](http://www.liferay.com/products/liferay-portal/overview)

Comment: Do you have hands on experience with Liferay?

Comment: Almost none, unfortunately. But I know is is both CMS and portlet container and it has some Spring support.

Comment: this was closed as not constructive, but is there a place in the stack exchange universe to ask this, i think its an extremely useful question -- that i am also facing-

Answer (score 0):

Here's how Daisy stacks up against your requirements:

- **Mobile**: I have built a mobile Daisy interface using Sencha Touch. It works very well
- **Layout Control**: Site styling is not accessible from the frontend.
- **Search**: Search is excellent in Daisy. It filters results based on access previleges and is very fast.

Daisy also has tremendous support for multilingual sites and content.